# storefront value is nil in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

storefront value is nil in iOS 14,
I have verified the value in iOS 13 and could get proper values. but value is always nil when I tried on iOS 14.4
code reference

`SKPaymentQueue.default().storefront?.countryCode`

Comment: Did you figure out why? We see this also from time to time on iOS 15